# Image Object is painted over itself

Tags: java, image, jframe, jlabel

I am trying to make a simple BrickBreaker game using a paddle. Yet I am a bit new to Java graphics and need some help.

Right now, my paddle object is painted over itself so that it creates something like this:
[image]

I can't understand why this happens. Following are my classes:

**Frame.java**

```
package STEMFairProject;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Frame extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

    private int WIDTH = 1400, HEIGHT = 780, paddleXPos = WIDTH/2 - 46, paddleYPos = HEIGHT - 59, paddleYVal, paddleXVale;
    private Dimension screenBounds = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    private Rectangle screenSize = new Rectangle(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    public Frame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Brick Breaker");
        setResizable(false);
        paintBackground();
        paintPaddle();
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void paintPaddle() {
        setLayout(null);    
        setSize(this.screenBounds);
        Paddle paddle = new Paddle();
        add (paddle);
        paddle.setBounds(paddleXPos, paddleYPos, 182, 38);
        addKeyListener(this);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintBackground() {
        BackgroundImage bgImage = new BackgroundImage();
        add (bgImage);
        bgImage.setBounds(this.screenSize);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            paddleXPos -= 10;
        }
        else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            paddleXPos += 10;

        }
        paintPaddle();  
        paintBackground();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**Paddle.java**

```
package STEMFairProject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Paddle extends JPanel{

    private JLabel img;

    public Paddle(){
        setLayout(null);
        try {
            img = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/vaibhavbajaj/Documents/Images/Ships.jpg"))));
            img.setBounds(0, 0, 182, 38);
            add(img);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Paddle Image not found");
        }
    }

    public JLabel getImg() {
        return img;
    }

}
```

**BackgroundImage.java**

```
package STEMFairProject;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BackgroundImage extends JPanel {

    private JLabel bgImage;
    private final int WIDTH = 1400, HEIGHT = 780;

    public BackgroundImage() {

        setLayout(null);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

        try {
            bgImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/vaibhavbajaj/Documents/Images/BackgroundImage.jpg"))));
            bgImage.setBounds(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            add(bgImage);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Background Image not found");
        }
    }

}
```

One wierd thing I have noted is that I paint the paddle first and then the background and yet the background comes in the back and the paddle in the front.

Comment: Why not read the Swing graphics tutorials before doing this, including [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html), an introductory tutorial to Swing graphics and: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), a more advanced tutorial on Swing graphics?

Comment: You keep creating new paddles in `paintPaddle()` so what else should happen than what you have right now? They don't magically disappear.

Comment: @Tom Why does the `paintBackground()` function not overwrite on top of the previous paddle?

Comment: The more I look at this code the more problems I see. For your sanity and for ours, scrap this code, it's not salvageable, and start over using proper first principles, including how to draw on a JPanel, use of Swing Timer, respecting Swing layouts, avoiding trying to plop components on top of each other in this way and expecting them to work....

Comment: I guess you mean "cover", not "overwrite", but it already does that. But since the upper panel has been moved, it can't cover everything.

Comment: @Tom Please explain a little better. Sorry for the inconvenience I am causing...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That is what I am starting to think as well. Would you know of any good tutorials to understand Swing graphics properly?

Comment: I've already given you two great links!

Comment: Btw: calling `addKeyListener(this)` in a method that is supposed to paint something seems to be a great source for more issues. If you've done that 50 times (for example), then your action will be performed 50 times when pressing a certain key.

Comment: @Tom Wow, didn't realise that was how that worked. I kinda get your point now.

Comment: It looks as if you're trying to throw out random code just to see if any of it works, but that's a guarantee of failure. Instead I suggest that you go through the tutorials, create **one** JPanel to do your painting, create your logical-non-GUI model objects including a logical representation of the game actors such as the paddle, boundaries, etc... then tie the model with the view using a binding Controller class.... again start with first principles.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That hurts (kidding). This is my first time creating a Java game so I was clueless as to how to proceed. Thanks a lot for the tutorials.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have a question. Can we use the `repaint()` and `paintComponent()` method for images as well? In essence, I want to know if a JPG, JPEG, or PNG image can be used in a Graphics object.